# What is difference between getDecorView() and peekDecorView() in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin, android-view

what is difference between getDecorView() and peekDecorView(),
what they return

Comment: I Have give you right Information then Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**getDecoreView :**

> Retrieve the top-level window decor view (containing the standard
>   window frame/decorations and the client's content inside of that),
>   which can be added as a window to the window manager.

```
Return : the top-level window decor view.
```

**peekDecorView() :**

> Retrieve the current decor view, but only if it has already been
>   created; otherwise returns null.

```
Return :  the top-level window decor or null.
```

Comment: should've named getTopLevelDecoreView and getCurrentDecoreView respectively.